# Python2 comments matter?

Tags: python, python-2.x

I know python2 is outdated, but I don't understand why comments matter in the following example:

```
$ python2 --version
Python 2.7.16
```

Without comments:

```py
class A:
    a = (0, "a")
    b = (1, "b")


a = filter(lambda x: getattr(A, x)[0]==1, dir(A))
print(a)
```

```
$ python2 b.py     
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "b.py", line 6, in <module>
    a = filter(lambda x: getattr(A, x)[0]==1, dir(A))
  File "b.py", line 6, in <lambda>
    a = filter(lambda x: getattr(A, x)[0]==1, dir(A))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

With comments:

```py
class A:
    """
    """
    a = (0, "a")
    b = (1, "b")


a = filter(lambda x: getattr(A, x)[0]==1, dir(A))
print(a)
```

```
$ python2 b.py
['b']
```

Comment: That isn't a comment (comments use `#`). That's a docstring, which is actually interned in the class object afaik.

Comment: I guess the docstring has an entry in `dir(A)` and if it's None then trying to use the `[]` operator on it will cause an exception.

Comment: @khelwood thanks! I think your comments answered my question.

Comment: @Carcigenicate and @khelwood have the right answer.  If the class does not have a docstring defined, its `__doc__` attribute will be `None`.  (And with your example, that is the *only* attribute that will be `None`.)

Comment: `print(dir(A))` would have given a strong clue.

Answer (score 2):

`docstrings` are a feature implemented into class objects of Python 2. You can find more information here: [Python Docstring](https://www.askpython.com/python/python-docstring)

They are very useful in determining what a class/method does.

If we take your class: `A`, and give it an appropriate `docstring`:

```
class A:
    """A Class assigns tuples to variable a and b """
    a = (0, "a")
    b = (1, "b")
```

We can call:

```
print(A.__doc__)
```

To easily find out what the method `A` does. By putting `docstrings` within the methods of a class, you can call those to find out what a specific method does.

Let me know if you have any other questions.